# exporting html data in json format

Tags: python, json, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame({'link' : ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke',
                             'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World']})

def puller(mylink):
    doc = requests.get(mylink)
    return BeautifulSoup(doc.content, 'html5lib')

df['parsed'] = df.link.apply(lambda x: puller(x))
```

This correctly pulls the html information of the wikipedia pages into the dataframe. I need to save that dataframe for later use. Unfortunately, the `parsed` column disappears when I export to `json`.

```
 df
Out[32]: 
                                                           link  \
0         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke   
1  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World   

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            parsed  
0  [html, [[\n, <meta charset="utf-8"/>, \n, <title>World's funniest joke - Wikipedia</title>, \n, <script>document.documentElement.className="client-js";RLCONF={"wgBreakFrames":!1,"wgSeparatorTransformTable":["",""],"wgDigitTransformTable":["",""],"wgDefaultDateFormat":"dmy","wgMonthNames":["","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"wgRequestId":"X@pXWwpAIDEAAE2fgjIAAABR","wgCSPNonce":!1,"wgCanonicalNamespace":"","wgCanonicalSpecialPageName":!1,"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"World's_funniest_joke","wgTitle":"World's funniest joke","wgCurRevisionId":966811540,"wgRevisionId":966811540,"wgArticleId":647561,"wgIsArticle":!0,"wgIsRedirect":!1,"wgAction":"view","wgUserName":null,"wgUserGroups":["*"],"wgCategories":["W...  
1  [html, [[\n, <meta charset="utf-8"/>, \n, <title>The Funniest Joke in the World - Wikipedia</title>, \n, <script>document.documentElement.className="client-js";RLCONF={"wgBreakFrames":!1,"wgSeparatorTransformTable":["",""],"wgDigitTransformTable":["",""],"wgDefaultDateFormat":"dmy","wgMonthNames":["","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"wgRequestId":"X@pjbgpAICMAADkWE2kAAACQ","wgCSPNonce":!1,"wgCanonicalNamespace":"","wgCanonicalSpecialPageName":!1,"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World","wgTitle":"The Funniest Joke in the World","wgCurRevisionId":996508425,"wgRevisionId":996508425,"wgArticleId":19164,"wgIsArticle":!0,"wgIsRedirect":!1,"wgAction":"view","wgUserName":null,"wgUserGroups...
```

but

```
df.to_json('myjson.json')
df = pd.read_json('myjson.json')
df
Out[30]: 
                                                           link  parsed
0         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke     NaN
1  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World     NaN
```

What is the issue here? Alternatively, what would be the best format to store this dataframe? `csv` tend to break down with so many weird html characters...

Thanks!

Comment: could be because the html contains double-quotes, does it NEED to be in pandas? Are you just trying to store the raw HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pandas doesn't know how to properly handle character escaping in this instance in json. If you don't need to use pandas you can do something like:

```py
import json
import requests


def write_json(data, path: str, indent: int = 4):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=indent)


def read_json(path: str):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)


links = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_funniest_joke',
         'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World']


html_data = {link: str(requests.get(link).content)
             for link in links}


write_json(html_data, './html_data.json')

print(json.dumps(read_json('./html_data.json'), indent=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the `bs4.BeautifulSoup` type to `str` type.

```
df['parsed'] = df['parsed'].map(str)
df.to_json('myjson.json')
df = pd.read_json('myjson.json')
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code it seen that you are doing web scraping for that use some third party. in python use this

```
json.dumps({
```

'url': str(urls),
'uid': str(uniqueID),
'page_content': htmlContent.text,
'date': finalDate
})